# A upper bound to the distribution of the sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let be $X,Y$ random variables and $\epsilon>0$. Then

$$
\mathbb{P}[X+Y\leq x]\leq \mathbb{P}[X\leq x] +\mathbb{P}[|Y|>\epsilon]+\epsilon.
$$

My idea to prove the inequality is using the next:
\begin{align*}
 \{X+Y\leq x\}&= \{X+Y\leq x, X\leq x\}\cup  \{X+Y\leq x ,X\geq x\}\\
&=\{X+Y\leq x, X\leq x\}\cup  \{Y\leq 0 ,X\geq x\}\\
&\subset \{ X\leq x\}\cup  \{Y\leq 0 \}\\
&\subset \{ X\leq x\}\cup  \{|Y|\leq  \epsilon \}\cup\{|Y|>  \epsilon \}.
\end{align*}
Integrating and using subadditivity, we get
$$
\mathbb{P}[X+Y\leq x]\leq \mathbb{P}[X\leq x] +\mathbb{P}[|Y|>\epsilon]+\mathbb{P}[|Y|\leq \epsilon].
$$
But I think  we need to use something like $\mathbb{E}[|Y|1_{A\cap \{|Y|\leq \epsilon\}}]\leq  \epsilon$ (for any event $A$) to get the desired inequality. Any suggestion woul be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stated inequality is false. For a counter-example take $X=\frac  1 4, Y=-\frac 1 4. x=\frac1  5$ and $\epsilon =\frac1  2 $.